# Do we need a visa? Vietnamese with Australian visa travelling SYD-TPE-ICN-TPE-SYD

Tags: visas, south-korea, vietnamese-citizens

I've read the [Timatic guide](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=VN&NV=Vietnam&DC=KR&DV=Korea%2C%20Republic%20of&h=886f623ea0d893bbb47e3db49db1f3f4f92f67d0) for visa exclusions but I'm not sure if our trip is covered by the given itineraries. Any help would be very appreciated!

My partner is Vietnamese with an Australian visa and we are flying from Sydney to Taipei and staying 3 nights before hitting Seoul for another 3 nights before flying back to Sydney via Taipei (2hr layover)

If we don't count the stopover as another country - it seems like our trip is:

> arrive from a third country (Taiwan) and departing to the country that issued the visa (Australia)"

But if we count the stopover - we end up with something like:

> arrive from a third country (Taiwan) and depart to another country (also Taiwan) for a maximum stay of 3 days, before departing to the country that issued the visa (Australia)

Below is the complete list of itineraries from the Titamic guide:

> The following itineraries are possible:
>   - arrive from a third country and departing to the country that issued the visa (e.g. DEL-ICN-YVR); or
>   - arrive from a third country and depart to another country for a maximum stay of 3 days, before departing to the country that issued
>   the visa (e.g. DEL-ICN-SGN-YVR); or
>   - arrive after transiting through a third country for a maximum of 3 days (e.g. DEL-SGN-ICN-YVR).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Timatic, they have full right to forbid entrance to Korea. The exemptions are clearly transit extensions. Your itinerary SYD - TPE - ICN - X/TPE - SYD is a simple round trip and can't be treated as transit. Such itinerary is not a transit as you return to the same place via the same route.